# Display array of words in reverse order

Tags: java, string, token, tokenize, sentence

I have some of my code already done I just do not know how I would display the sentence in reverse order than what is entered.
For example; if one enters "my name is joe"
It should display in the output: Joe
                                 is
                                 name
                                 my

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Sentence {
     public static void main(String [] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
         String sentence = input.nextLine();

         String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

         // Display the array of words in 
         // reverse order
     }
 }
```

Comment: You know how to use `System.out.print()`, do you know how to access an element in an array? If yes, then what is it you have problems with? I guess you are not the one who wrote this code, then.

Comment: Thanks, only how to display it in reverse than what is entered.

Comment: What did you find after exhaustively investigating your use case in other Stack Overflow posts?

Comment: I only found questions relating to this in C++, not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can do something like that:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String sentence = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you did there.